# have both caps lock and multiple lines in Android softkey pad

Tags: android, text, view

I want my keyboard to have caps lock on, this is done by

```
mEditText.setInputType(TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS);
```

I also want the action button to be used as a <kbd>Return</kbd> button, meaning go to the beginning of next line. This is how the keyboard opens for me by default, and can also be doneby

```
mEditText.setInputType(131073);
```

My question is, is there a way for them to co-exist? To have both caps lock and a return button? I tried the option:

```
mEditText.setInputType(TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_MULTI_LINE);
```

but it really does nothing helpful :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a guess but have you tried:

```
mEditText.setInputType(TYPE_TEXT_FLAG_CAP_CHARACTERS | 131073);
```

Comment: MIND. BLOWN. 2 hours of rage and you solved it in 2 minutes. You are my hero.